# Strip space in XML tag value based on length condition using XSLT

Tags: xslt, trim

I have a very simple query, but not able to find the easiest/elegant way to solve it. If my input XML has a tag with string content "YY nnn" where YY is alphanumeric 2 characters, followed by a space, and then upto 4 numerics. In my output XML I need to strip the space if the numerics are 4 characters - ie. "YY nnnn" and retain the space if "YY nnn". I have tried with a string length check and then strip the space, but I'm sure there must be a simpler way.

Any ideas?

I am using xlstproc on linux for the transforms.

Thanks!

Comment: hey what if the count is neither 3 nor 4, like say it is 5 or 2 `("A1 23456" or "BZ 12")` should we retain space or not??

Comment: well. In my code I am copying as it is .. not stripping-away the space in `<xsl:otherwise>`. Change it as your requirement. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <MyNode>AZ 1234</MyNode>
  <MyNode>A3 123</MyNode>
  <MyNode>7Z 12345</MyNode>
  <MyNode>15 23</MyNode>
</root>
```

XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MyNode">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(substring-after(.,' '))='4'">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,' '), substring-after(.,' '))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(substring-after(.,' '))='3'">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <MyNode>AZ1234</MyNode>
  <MyNode>A3 123</MyNode>
  <MyNode>7Z 12345</MyNode>
  <MyNode>15 23</MyNode>
</root>
```

Comment: @Surge, no. This is the only way possible. Even with XSLT 2.0, **I think** this would be the possible approach.

Comment: Thanks Aravind - thought there might be some concise way wherein I could check for 7 chars (YY_NNNN) and do a translate() or a concat(), else just leave the input alone. To answer your earlier question, it won't exceed 4 numerics. The minimum could be YY_N (one numeric).

Comment: Glad it could help you. Let me know if any questions :)